# Django simple categories list

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

Sorry for asking such a simple question, but I got stuck on (as I think) this trivial problem. I have a simple gallery model in Django and want to get a category list for photos. My model looks like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORIES)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And the `choices.py` file looks like this:

```
CATEGORIES = (
    (1, ('Mountains')),
    (2, ('Animals')),
    (3, ('Macro')),
    (4, ('People'))
)
```

What I'm looking for is getting a list like this:

```
Mountains | Animals | Macro | People
```

in my templates.

Comment: You aware that one photo can have one category, so you can't have all the categories displayed in the template unless you just use it through a context view and loop through it in templates

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? To the downvoter: please explain the reason or take back your downvote. We don't want to discourage new users of posting questions. This question doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create model form for this,

models.py

```
CATEGORIES = (
    (1, 'Mountains'),
    (2, 'Animals'),
    (3, 'Macro'),
    (4, 'People')
)

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORIES)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Photo

class PhotoModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['__all__']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
form .forms import PhotoModelForm
def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PhotoModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PhotoModelForm()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

template.py:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
```

> What I'm looking for is getting a list like this:
>
> ```
> Mountains | Animals | Macro | People
> ```

Create New form like,

```
 class PhotosForm(forms.Form):
        category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORIES)
```

Add view to views.py

```
def show_list(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = PhotosForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            photos = Photo.objects.filter(category=form.cleaned_data['category'])
            context['photos'] = photos
    else:
        context['form'] = PhotosForm()
        context['categories'] = dict((x, y ) for x, y in CATEGORIES)
    return render(request, 'template1.html', context)
```

And at last you need to add template,

```
{% if photos %}


<display pics>

{% else %}


{% for key, value in categories %}

     <a href='showpics?id={{key}}'>{{value}}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

And last `showpics` should be point to `show_list`

Comment: The answer is nice and thorough. It goes all the way through from the models to the templates and explains how to create new objects. However the OP asked something slightly different.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, finally I can move on with my project. Actually all I needed was that part in views and templete.